# Load a database to Ormlite with sql queries

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I already have a bunch of sql create table queries and injections written. How can I load these in to my android app using Ormlite? From what I understand the data base is created like this in the examples:

```
        @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
        private Integer id;

        @DatabaseField
        private String description;
...
    TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Thing.class);
```

I would want to do this automagically the other way around with ex:

```
CREATE TABLE "History" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL , "date" DATETIME, "program_id" INTEGER, "FOREIGN KEY(program_id) REFERENCES Program (_id)" );
```

Best thing would be to read from a textfile added i resources.

As you can see Im a bit confused about this, can something like this be done? Should also mention that Im using foreign keys, is it supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me that you need to match your objects to your create statements.  For example, if you want to do the following create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE "History" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
    "date" DATETIME, "program_id" INTEGER,
    "FOREIGN KEY(program_id) REFERENCES Program (_id)" );
```

Then you should should construct the following Java to correspond to it:

```
 public class History {
      // maybe generatedId = true
      @DatabaseField(columnName = "_id", nullable = false, id = true)
      public int id;
      @DatabaseField(/* not sure if you need to set a date type here */
      public Date date;
      @DatabaseField(foreign = true, columnName = "program_id")
      public Program program;
 }

 public class Program {
      // maybe generatedId = true
      @DatabaseField(columnName = "_id", nullable = false, id = true)
      public int id;
      ...
 }
```

You can do your own create and then tweak the corresponding Java classe so they are able to persist to the tables -- matching the columns with the fields.